# What is the answer when integer added to string constant in C language?

Tags: c, string, pointer-arithmetic

`char c=8+"ab";` //output is `c=112` with warning

`int c=8+"ab";` //output is `c=4195952` with warning

`char c=8+"a";` //output is `c=112` (same as many caharacters in string constants) with warning

How is c value computed here?
Please explain.

Comment: This is dangerous.

Comment: What are you *expecting* the result to be?  Do you think adding a string literal to an integer should have a meaningful result?  Do you think that result should fit into a single `char` or `int` object?

Comment: Open a C book before write random characters to claim it's C code ;) [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Dixith Reddy Anything else needed to help solve this post?

Answer (score 3):

`"ab"` is a `char *`. You can add an integer offset to a pointer, so `8 + "ab"` is a `char *` pointer a few characters past the end of the string.

Then (and this will warn you) you can cast a pointer to an integer type. So `int c=8+"ab"` gives you the lower 32 bits of the pointer (assuming 32-bit `int`) and `char c=8+"ab"` gives you just the lowest 8 bits.

The actual value is undefined and of no use here, just don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

`0+"ab"` is a well defined pointer addition.  Result: the `char *` pointer to the zero-th element `'a'`.

`1+"ab"` is a well defined pointer addition.  Result: the `char *` pointer to the element  1: `'b'`.

`2+"ab"` is a well defined pointer addition.  Result: the `char *` pointer to the element  2: `'\0'`.

`3+"ab"` is a well defined pointer addition.  Result: the `char *` pointer 1 passed `2+"ab"`.

`8+"ab"` is not well defined pointer addition as the answer does not lie within the *string literal* or one past. The result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

> How is c value computed here?

As all OP's examples use `8+"ab";`.  All are UB.  Reported results have no specified meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider for example this declaration

```
char c=8+"ab";
```

The string literal "ab" is a character array with type `char[3]`.

In the expression `8 + "ab"` this array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character. So the expression has the type `char *` and points outside the array because the array has only three elements.

As result the character is initialized by the address outside the array converted to the type `char` that does not make sense and can lead to undefined behavior.

As for the output you have for the character `c` then in fact it is due to the conversion

```
char c = 4195952;
```

Comment: Your last statement seems a bit off: the pointer is never dereferenced so whatever is stored there is never accessed.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski I wasn't objecting to saying it was undefined behaviour, I was objecting to Vlad's original statement that said it used the value at that location (which he has now corrected).

Answer (score 1):

You are causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As already explained by others, this is basically a pointer arithmetic, and according to the spec, `C11`, chapter §6.5.6

> [...] If both the pointer
>   operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
>   element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

your pointer arithmetic takes the result well past the "one past the last
element of the array object", so you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)